# Is there a way to get the Text of an element using its Xpath in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xpath

I need to get the text of an element by passing its Xpath in Java Script.

I am using an Automation Tool, Where it supports only JavaScript. And I need to get the Text of number of elements , where the element count changes dynamically. So, I want to get the text of the elements I want by passing the Xpath in JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `document.evaluate()`?

```
var h1_text = document.evaluate('//h1/text()', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
```